# playing boogie woogie triplets with 8th notes. timing

Tags: piano, rhythm

If the 8ths are swing, would not 2 8ths on the left hand be played at the exact time as triplets on the right hand?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I’m assuming you know this already but just to be clear the boogie swing 8th notes are the first and third notes of eighth note triplets, or if you think of it as 12/8 time they are quarter-eighth-quarter-eighth etc.

Here’s a basic example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A swing Boogie Woogie would be played with a triplet feel.